# Re Tactile metronome US 7268290 B2

Tags: patent-infringement, us7268290

Does this patent prevent another party from developing an electronic tactile metronome, or is it just protecting the particular configuration described?

Answer (score 1):

The claim wording of patents defines the scope. Claim 1 for example says:

> 1. A tactile metronome for use by a musician, said tactile metronome comprising:
>
>    **a signal generator** for producing an electrical signal according to a desired timing scheme that includes a complex beat pattern that are user definable, said timing scheme being produced by a controller;
>
>    **a tactile transducer** in electrical communication with said signal generator, said tactile transducer being adapted to impart a tactile stimulations to the musician corresponding to the complex beat pattern in response to said electrical signal; and
>
>    **a programming interface** to said controller, said programming interface being adapted to enable the user to input a rhythmic pattern to said controller wherein said rhythmic pattern is programmable within the tactile metronome from user selected musical score within said programming interface.

All of these things need to be present and inter-related in the manner specified by the claim in order to infringe this claim.